# What happens if my recaptcha secret key is stolen?

Tags: security, encryption, recaptcha, captcha

In the google website says

> The secret key authorizes communication between your application backend and the reCAPTCHA server to verify the user's response. The secret key needs to be kept safe for security purposes.

I want to know what are those security risks.